# Can I delegate an event and be able to invoke it as well?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I know I can delegate the subscription of my event to another event,

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { SomeClass.AnotherEvent += value; }
    remove { SomeClass.AnotherEvent -= value; }
}
```

In this case, if `AnotherEvent` is raised, then `MyEvent` will be raised as well.

However in my class I cannot raise MyEvent() on my own as usual, because it says:
 `Error 3   The event 'MyEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`

I assume this is because the delegation of the subscription above.

Is it possible that I can delegate a subscription as well as invoke it on my own? The objective is so that MyEvent can be raised by two things, `AnotherEvent` as well as my own code.

Comment: With which code do you try to raise "MyEvent"?

Comment: just some code in my method, like `MyEvent(this);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can - but you'll need your own delegate variable. You could either subscribe to `SomeClass.AnotherEvent` once and call your own delegate when that event is raised, or just keep subscribers twice:

```
private EventHandler myEvent;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        myEvent += value;
        SomeClass.AnotherEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        myEvent -= value;
        SomeClass.AnotherEvent -= value;
    }
}
```

Note that if you go for the "subscribe to SomeClass.AnotherEvent once" approach, you may want to consider *only* subscribing when you first see a subscription to `MyEvent`, and unsubscribing when `myEvent` becomes null after unsubscription. It can all get quite tricky in terms of disposal...

Comment: by "subscribe to SomeClass.AnotherEvent once" you mean Pete's and Akash's answers?

Comment: ok thanks. I thought of their solutions too and I imagined it would get tricky like you said. Your solution didn't occur to me, and I think it's much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wire up your other someclass's event..

```
// constructor or initializer..

SomeClass.AnotherEvent += (s,e)=>{
   if(MyEvent != null){
      MyEvent(s,e);
   }
};

// let this be implicit default event
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

protected void RaiseMyEvent(){
    if(MyEvent != null){
        MyEvent(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the delegate itself, not the event property. Because `MyEvent` doesn't have a backing field, that means you would have to invoke the backing field of `SomeClass.AnotherEvent`, which (usually) only `SomeClass` can do. As others have stated there are ways around this. See their answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, and if you could, I don't think that it would be logical. So I would implement the event normally, and then add an event handler to your class that listens to events from the other class.

You're basically making a class that has an event that is fired when something happens internally in the class AND something happens in a dependent class. I think that the implementation should reflect this. For example:

```
public MyClass()
{
    this.other = new SomeClass;
    other.AnotherEvent += SomeClass_AnotherEvent;
}
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
private void SomeClass_AnotherEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (MyEvent != null)
         MyEvent(this, e); // I think that it would be most logical, that you do not pass the sender
}
```